# Trigger to update value mysql

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, sql-update

I am quite new to SQL and am working on a small project, but I got stuck when wanting to implement triggers to my model.

I am designing a database for a sports league. I have a table "GamePlayed" with a column called "GoalsScored" and another one "Team" with a column called "GoalsFor". Those two tables are connected by the "TeamID" key.

I would like to have a trigger that updates the value of "GoalsFor" by adding to the previous value the value of "GoalsScored". In this way, with every game, the total quantity of goals scored will be constantly updated.

I tried the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "Goalsscored" AFTER UPDATE
ON `GamePlayed`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE `Team` SET `Team`.`GoalsFor`=`Team`.`GoalsFor`+`GamePlayed`.`GoalsScored` 
WHERE `GamePlayed`.`Team_TeamID`=`Team`.`TeamID`
END
```

Unfortunately, it says there is a problem in my SQL syntax...
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your delimiter. Something like this

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER "Goalsscored" AFTER UPDATE
ON `GamePlayed`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE `Team` SET `Team`.`GoalsFor`=`Team`.`GoalsFor`+`GamePlayed`.`GoalsScored` 
WHERE `GamePlayed`.`Team_TeamID`=`Team`.`TeamID`;
END;
$$
```

See eg http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html